VBA find 2nd, 3rd and 4th occurrences if multiple IF conditions met within FOR NEXT loop
Hello everyone and don't judge me a lot, as I'm not experienced VBA coder just time to time trying to make my life easier and automate some things...
I have 2 tables on 2 sheets and trying to fill T1 with data from T2, if multiple conditions are met...






Test

L1

L2

L3





A
B
C
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2


A1
1
C1










A1
2
C2










A2
3
C3










A1
4
C4














A
B1
B2
B3
B4
R
C
L
N




A1
1
2
3
4
Test
All
a
1


A1
1
2



C1
b
2


A2
1
2



C4
c
3


A1


3



d
4


A2
1

3
4

C2
e
5


A2





C2
f
6


A1
1




C2
g
7


A2

2




h
8


A2


3


C4
i
9


A2





C3
j
10


A1
1
2



C1
k
11


A1


3
4

C1
l
12



I've managed to get first 2 columns filled but can't get nth matching values...
some code below:
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim f As String

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("S")

For d = 4 To sht1.UsedRange.Rows.count
For e = 3 To sht2.UsedRange.Rows.count
For g = 5 To sht1.UsedRange.Columns.count

    a = sht1.Cells(d, 2).Value
    b = sht1.Cells(2, g).Value
    c = sht1.Cells(d, 3).Value
    f = sht1.Cells(d, 4).Value

If sht2.Cells(e, 2).Value = a _
    And sht2.Cells(e, 7).Value = b _
        And (sht2.Cells(e, 3).Value = c _
            Or sht2.Cells(e, 4).Value = c _
            Or sht2.Cells(e, 5).Value = c _
            Or sht2.Cells(e, 6).Value = c) _
        And sht2.Cells(e, 8).Value = "All" _
        And sht2.Cells(e, 8).Value <> "" _
    Then

    sht1.Cells(d, g).Value = sht2.Cells(e, 9).Value
    sht1.Cells(d, g + 1).Value = sht2.Cells(e, 10).Value

End If

If sht2.Cells(e, 2).Value = a _
    And b = "L1" _
        And (sht2.Cells(e, 3).Value = c _
            Or sht2.Cells(e, 4).Value = c _
            Or sht2.Cells(e, 5).Value = c _
            Or sht2.Cells(e, 6).Value = c) _
        And sht2.Cells(e, 8).Value = f _
        And sht2.Cells(e, 8).Value <> "" _
    Then

    sht1.Cells(d, g).Value = sht2.Cells(e, 9).Value
    sht1.Cells(d, g + 1).Value = sht2.Cells(e, 10).Value

End If

  If sht2.Cells(e, 2).Value = a _
    And b = "L2" _
        And (sht2.Cells(e, 3).Value = c _
            Or sht2.Cells(e, 4).Value = c _
            Or sht2.Cells(e, 5).Value = c _
            Or sht2.Cells(e, 6).Value = c) _
        And sht2.Cells(e, 8).Value = f _
        And sht2.Cells(e, 8).Value <> "" _
    Then

    sht1.Cells(d, g).Value = sht2.Cells(e, 9).Value
    sht1.Cells(d, g + 1).Value = sht2.Cells(e, 10).Value

End If

  Next g
    Next e
        Next d

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



Have you tried using Excel built in functionality, like say a VLOOKUP function?

What are multiple conditions?

Since your code doesn't do what you want, we can't read it to figure out what it is you want.  Please explain in words what it is you need to do.

Hi, need to match values between 2 tables in A, B and C. If all 3 matches values from second table L should go to L1, L2 and L3 first column, from N to second column. Code is working up until I need to find second or further matches.

For Col B matching, do you mean Col B in table 1 matchs one of Col B1 to B4 in table2?

Do both tables start from cell A1 on the sheet?


It appears that neither table starts from cell A1. Please include this detail in your post, as it is essential for the coding process.

Additionally, there is a logical error in your nested loops. The script consistently populates data on L1.


Option Explicit
Sub FillTable()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim c As String
    Dim f As String
    Dim d As Long, e As Long, g As Long
    Const START_COL = 7 ' Col# of L1
    Const GROUP_CNT = 3 ' L1, L2, L3
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("S")
    For d = 4 To sht1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        sht1.Cells(d, 7).Resize(, GROUP_CNT * 2).ClearContents
        For e = 3 To sht2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            a = sht1.Cells(d, 2).Value
            c = sht1.Cells(d, 3).Value
            f = sht1.Cells(d, 4).Value
            If sht2.Cells(e, 2).Value = a And _
                (sht2.Cells(e, 3).Value = c Or sht2.Cells(e, 4).Value = c Or _
                    sht2.Cells(e, 5).Value = c Or sht2.Cells(e, 6).Value = c) _
                And sht2.Cells(e, 8).Value = f Then
                For g = START_COL To START_COL + GROUP_CNT * 2 Step 2
                    If Len(sht1.Cells(d, g).Value) = 0 Then
                        sht1.Cells(d, g).Resize(, 2).Value = sht2.Cells(e, 9).Resize(, 2).Value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next e
    Next d
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


